# Visualizing the structure of a Fortran program

Tags: fortran, subroutine

I am learning a new program in Fortran 90 that has its subroutines in others external files. I wondered is there is any way to have a scheme that can let me see how this files are connected?

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Be aware that Fortran 90 is very old and most programs use some more recent versions of the standard even if the file is named .f90.

Comment: Take a look at [i-Code](https://analysis-tools.dev/tool/i-code-cnes-for-fortran) which comes with an Eclipse UI.

Comment: Many years ago I used Understand from [SciTools](https://www.scitools.com/) for similar purpose.

Comment: We used plusFort(specifically SPAG) from Polyheadron back in the day